# Cocoapod update taking too long

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, cocoapods

I had added TestFlight cocapod in my application. Now when its going to app store, I want to remove it from cocoa pod

I followed the steps as :

-> Removed testflight line from pod file

-> Went to terminal and path to the project folder

-> From terminal fire the command "pod update"

-> It stuck at "Analyzing Dependencies" and not going further

How can I update pod in this case? I am using xcode5

Comment: You need to install "Command Line Tool" of xcode. XCode->Preferences->Downloads->Command Line Tool. Install this and try again